# how to install qt specific version libraries

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I need to install qt libraries 5.9 in Ubuntu 20.04.
sudo apt install qt5-default
will bring the latest qt release which I don't want.

I need specific qt libraries for compatibility reasons. I have applications running in the field where qt libraries are pre installed as dinamic libraries in the targets and can must be kept unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu only offers the versions available in their repos.

If you want a specific version you can download the Qt installer (https://www.qt.io/download) and search for the version you need there. You'll find a list of builds available for download.

However, not all versions are available in their repos as well. In that case you'll have to build the version you need yourself I guess.